# Trigger certain button on 'enter' keypress in ngForm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

From AngularJS documentation on ngForm:
"if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter in any of the input fields will trigger the click handler on the first button or input[type=submit] (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (ngSubmit)"
**Question:**
Is there any way to trigger certain button instead "first"?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more.. are you trying to make sure they have filled out two fields? If so you could use require/validate?

Comment: No, I just have big form and use <button> elements inside it (like remove e-mail field, remove phone field etc). Below the form I have submit button. And when I press enter in one of input fields it removes e-mail field for example instead of submitting.

Comment: you can define `ng-submit` on form element which will point to your function which you want to trigger... but I don't quite get why you want to have multiple submit buttons in one form

Comment: @doodeec Documentation says that first button would be triggered anyway. And I don't have multiple submit buttons in form. It's just buttons with ngClick, I use them to modify form.

Comment: @mkrakhin if you define `<form ng-submit="myFunction()">` you don't care how many buttons there are and what their ngClicks do, after hitting enter, myFunction will always be triggered... at least I think so

Comment: No, I already tried this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`button` element by default has "submit" type (except in IE), so if you have `<button></button>` inside your `form` then that's the button that will be triggered on `enter`.

Explicitly set the type to "button" if you want to skip that button on `enter`.

```html
// Will not trigger form submit
<button type="button">Click me</button>

// *Will* trigger form submit
<button>Submit</button>
// or
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: * Note to other people - this doesn't solve the problem with `<ng-form>`, `<form>` by default has this default behavior, but not `<ng-form>`